# compilation error when integrating Fabric Twitter Kit in android

Tags: twitter, android-twitter, twitter-fabric

I am an android developer. I have a problem by using Fabric SDK for android.

I tried to integrate Twitter-Kit for my own implemented application.
My application android build version is Android 2.3.3 (Api level 10).

After adding kit-libs to my project i am getting compilation error because of some theme and resources are missed. 
I figured out the root cause for the issues.

That is because of kit-libs android jars required android build version Android 5.0 (Api level 21).
So some of the resources are missed when i integrated the kit-libs to my own project which is supporting from android api level 10.

Please suggest me how can i use this Twitter-Kit( kit-libs) for my application which is build on android api level 10.
I am suspecting the issue with supporting libraries are mismatched in my application and integrated fabric twitter kit library apps.

Please let me know how can i check the problem with supporting lib's are not.

Please find the attached screen for my problem.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got answer for my question.

Root cause:

It is the problem when i integrate Fabric Twitter Kit into my application.
Some mismatch happen for my application targetSdkVersion and twitter library projects targetSdkVersion.

While integrating twitter the following property `manifestmerger.enabled=true` was added in my project.properties file. Because of this property my application is mismatching targetSdkVersion.

Solution:

Just commented `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in project.properties file.
Make sure is there any dependencies with that property before you are going to make comment out(or remove). For me it was added after integrating twitter kit for my android application.